# Itextsharp: Error when decoding a creationdate on PDF File

Tags: .net, vb.net, itext

I'm getting the following error when decoding a creation date:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
occurred in mscorlib.dll
Hour, Minute, and Second parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.
```

I'm doing `pdfdate.decode(xdoc.info("creationdate"))`

Here's the info from the PDF file:

```
/CreationDate (D:191010319150120)
/Producer (Acrobat Distiller Daemon 3.01 for Solaris 2.3 and later \(SPARC\))
/Creator (tif_convert_2_ps\(\))
/Title (/tardir/tiffs/a386689.tiff)
/ModDate (D:20010320070957)
```

The Modification date seems to be a valid date, but, the creation date looks
kinda weird to me...

More intriguing is that when I get the properties of this file using Adobe Reader it shows
a valid date for the creation date field.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Distiller versions prior to 3.02 had a Y2K bug which caused them to write invalid CreationDate values for files created on or after January 1, 2000. Here's a link to the patch which corrected this problem for Distiller 3.02:

http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=661

Your PDF was created by Distiller 3.01, so it has the bug. Its CreationDate of "191010319150120" is "19101" (e.g., 101 years after the base year of 1900, or 2001), "0319" for 19 March, "150120" for 15:01:20 (3:01:20 PM); I'd assume this date/time is UTC, and that your server is 8 hours behind UTC, causing the time to display as 7:01:20 AM the same day.

I don't know of a way to fix the CreationDate value: current versions of Acrobat and Reader can clearly display the invalid string correctly, but I doubt the function you're using has that hack. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The PDF Spec says that PDF dates are defined thusly:

```
D:YYYYMMDDHHmmSSOHH'mm
D:191010319150120
```

is
1910, October(10) 31 (Halloween), 91h, 50m, 12s 0

I do believe the "91h" is the problem... and the trailing 0 should be a plus or minus as part of a UT offset (the "HH'mm" portion).

Adobe is probably more fault tolerant, perhaps MOD-24'ing the hours and ignoring the zero.  Looks like we need to spruce up our code to match.  Out of curiousity, what date does Reader show?

Comment: Thanks for you answer Mark. It shows the following: 
Creation Date: Monday, March 19, 2001, 7:01:20 AM
Modification Date: Monday, March 19, 2001, 11:09:57 PM

Here's the file in question if you want to take a look:
http://edocs.nps.edu/npspubs/scholarly/theses/2000/Dec/00Dec_Gossett.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: Wow.  That makes no sense whatsoever.  Sweet.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: It's really weird...I tried using Foxit, but it doesn't show the same date as Adobe Reader. It shows the following in the Creation Date, 
Created: 60365-154-154- 59480:152:11376
Modified: 2001-03-20 06:09:07

Comment: I wonder what the date would be if you interpreted that as a second count a la unix time.  It's a 48-bit value... huh.  As miliseconds, it works out to jan 20... 1976.  As seconds, its in the year 8022.  So much for that theory.  I'll plead insanity.

Answer (score 1):

I run into similar example too - This looks like y2k bug to me :) Replace "191" with "20" and you get good date format...